# Сложение свойств объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо в объект записать свойства двух других объектов, но при этом одинаковые свойства не заменять, а складывать значения ключей. Пример:

```
let object1 = {
  'ключ1': 100,
  'ключ2': 100
};

let object2 = {
  'ключ2': 10,
  'ключ3': 10
};

/*
  Желаемый результат:

  object3 = {
    'ключ1': 100,
    'ключ2': 110,
    'ключ3': 10
  }
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно циклами и проверкой на наличие:

```js
let object1 = {
  'ключ1': 100,
  'ключ2': 100
};

let object2 = {
  'ключ2': 10,
  'ключ3': 10
};

let object3 = {};

// Создаём цикл с массивом, в который вводим массивы, которые нужно сложить
for(var i = 0, arrays = [object1, object2]; i < arrays.length; i++){
  for(key in arrays[i]){
    if(object3[key] == undefined){
      object3[key] = arrays[i][key];
    }else{
      object3[key] = parseFloat(object3[key]) + parseFloat(arrays[i][key]);
    };
  };
};

console.log(object3);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let object1 = {
  'ключ1': 100,
  'ключ2': 100
};

let object2 = {
  'ключ2': 10,
  'ключ3': 10
};

let object3 = {
  'ключ2': 10,
  'ключ3': 10
};


const sumValueByKey = (...rest) => rest.reduce( ( result, current ) => {
  for(let key in current){
      let value = current[key];
      
      if(result[key] === undefined){
        result[key] = value;
      }else{
        result[key] += value;
      }
  }
  
  return result;
}, {} );


console.log(sumValueByKey(object1, object2, object3));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var Vector = (function() {
    var Vector = function(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };
    Vector.prototype = {
        plus : function(a) {
            return new Vector(this.x + a.x,this.y + a.y);
        },
        minus : function(a) { 
            return new Vector(this.x - a.x,this.y - a.y);
        }
    };
    return Vector;
})();
var a = new Vector(1,2);
var b = a.plus(new Vector(3,4));
//b = {
x :4,
y :6
}
```